# How can I determine if there is mold on my fieldstone basement walls?

Tags: mold

I recently purchased a home built in 1908 which has a fieldstone foundation. The basement remains unfinished and has a cold room. Recently water started appearing on the basement floor and I want to repoint the foundation walls.  How can I tell if there is mold on or in the walls and how can I prevent further mold once the repointing is completed?